# How to tell Rails that the action has no template or view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action into my controller who no need template or view

Puma's log

```
No template found for CartController#post, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 2249ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms | Allocations: 27968)
```

How to tell Rails there is no template need ?

Comment: show your action code -- but all you need to do is return a `head :ok` or similar response

Comment: @dbugger Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want an action to return with no content then use the [head](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head) method to just return with an HTTP status code.

In your example (`CartController#post`) the most appropriate response might be

```
head :created
```

to return with an HTTP `201 Create` status code without further content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
render json: @foo
```